# Is it possible no one gets any gift?

Tags: combinatorics

> We have 20 kinds of presents; this time, we have a large supply of each kind. We want to give presents to 12 children. Again, it is not required that every child gets something; but no child can get two copies of the same present. In how many ways can we give presents?

Someone has posted this question but I still have one more question about this. The solution is $(2^{20})^{12}$. Child A can either get 1st gift or not. There are 20 kinds of gifts and 12 children, so we have $(2^{20})^{12}$. Does this mean that it is possible that no children get any gift? Are we supposed to consider this case?

Comment: Nothing in the problem statement precludes the "empty solution", i.e. the one in which no kid gets a present.

Comment: Thanks. I just found it odd that possibly no children is going to receive gift.

Comment: Well, of course we here have no way of knowing what the intent behind the problem was.  All we have is the bare statement of the problem.  If you suspect the intent was something else, you should ask whomever set the problem.

Comment: Please consider mentioning the source of the problem. Please consider checking whether there are other questions on Math SE on this problem — indeed, there are. Please consider linking to them. There is no point in answering the very same question over and over again, especially so if unaware of other answers to it. It is Sisyphean.

Answer (score 1):

I will explain what $(2^{20})^{12}$ means.

Fix one child, call him A. A can **get** a gift of the first type, or A can **not get** a gift of the first type, so there are
$$
2 \text{ ways}
$$
Now A can **get** the gift of the second type, or A can **not get** the gift of the second type, so there are, by multiplicative principle
$$
2^2 \text{ ways}
$$
So eventually, because there are 20 types of gifts, the choices of what gifts A gets are
$$
2^{20} \text{ ways}
$$
Which obviously includes the possibility that A gets **nothing**. I hope you can continue from here.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I understood the idea, but I found it odd that it is possible that no children is going to get any present.

Answer (score 0):

In ordinary English, to give presents to $12$ children means there are $12$ children and each receives at least one present.

But in this problem we are told it is not required that every child gets a present.
Clearly it is possible that only $11$ children get presents and the last child gets nothing.
In ordinary English, I would not call that "giving presents to $12$ children."
I would call it "giving presents to $11$ children."

After all, if you were running a business and you say, "At the end of the week I have to pay $12$ employees," you are not thinking it is OK for only $11$ employees to get money at the end of the week and Joe gets nothing that week.

So we have a signal that we are not to use the ordinary English meaning of "give presents".
We are instead using a special mathematical language in which "give presents" means "give zero or more presents."

Then if no child receives a present, we have given zero or more presents to each child, so this is within the possible outcomes of the question.